# I want to display two like operators in case statement but it throws an error

Tags: sql

(case when disch_disp like '%Home%' and disp.name like '%Home%' then 'Y'
  when disch_disp in '%Facility%' and disp.name like '%Facility%' then 'Y' 
 else 'N'
end )  as match

Comment: `disch_disp in '%Facility%' ` is not valid.

Comment: @pmbAustin that would not be valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo, that's all. LIke '%facility%' not IN.

```
(case when disch_disp like '%Home%' and disp.name like '%Home%' then 'Y'
when disch_disp LIKE '%Facility%' and disp.name like '%Facility%' then 'Y' else 'N'
end ) as match
```